# Images do not load if they have hyphens in their name, are long or depending on their location

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have some images for my website under `C:\xampp\htdocs\catshop\assets\img`. If an image has a name like `food-adult-wet-meo-sardine-in-prawn-jelly-400g` it is not displayed on the site. However, if the name is like `can1.png` or `can-1.png`, it gets displayed properly (despite being in the same location). If I name it `food-prawnjelly.png` it does not get displayed, even if it has just one hyphen. `foodprawnjelly.png` doesn't work either

If I move the image to `C:\xampp\htdocs\catshop\assets\img\food` then it won't get displayed either, even if it's name is something which "worked" previously like `can1.png`.

I don't know if it's relevant or if this is what is causing the problem, but I'm using rewrite rules to make pretty links. A link like `catshop/food/adult-cat.food` gets rewritten to `show-category.php` where the appropriate filetering occurs to show products from `adult-cat-food`. I have used absolute links for the image paths (e.g. `/catshop/assets/img/can-1.png`)

Rewrite rule used: `RewriteRule    ^(\w+)/(\w+)$  show-category.php    [NE,L]`

Let me know if I need to provide more info, thanks!

```
catshop
├─ .htaccess
├─ assets
│  ├─ bootstrap
│  ├─ css
│  ├─ fonts
│  ├─ img
│  │  ├─ can-1.png
│  └─ js
├─ index.php
├─ login.php
├─ register.php
├─ show-category.php
└─ logout.php
```

Edit: contents of .htacess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
    RewriteRule    home   index.php    [NC,L]    
    RewriteRule    food   show-category.php    [NC,L]    

    RewriteRule   ^((\w+)\/)+(\w.+)$  show-category.php    [NE,L]    

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding,

1. You are looking for images etc to resolve directly from the `/catshop/assets` location
2. Any .php file must resolve
3. Any other url (not containing the word "home") must resolve to `/catshop/show-category.php`

(Of note: you may which to change the use of home as this will match any string that contains the word home at any point)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
    RewriteRule    home   index.php    [NC,L]    
    RewriteRule   ^((?!assets)\w+\/)+(\w+\.\w+)(?<!\.php)$  catshop/show-category.php    [NE,L]    

</IfModule>
```

This will look for any url part that doesn't contain the the word `assets` or `.php`

Comment: I forgot to mention, I also have a URL `catshop/food` which also gets mapped to show-category.php via another rewrite rule (I know not the best way, but just trying to get it to work for now). Images don't show up there either. Tried your solution, but still doesn't work. I'll update the post with the content of the .htaccess

Comment: @rhododendron I think I may have misinterpreted the question, is the intention for only  /catshop/food/... to resolve to show-category.php?

Comment: /catshop/food, /catshop/food/adult-cat-food,  /catshop/food/adult-cat-food/wet-cat-food all should redirect to show-category.php (There'll be other pages too afterwards like /catshop/litter/... , /catshop/supplies/... )

Comment: @rhododendron New answer posted.